# volume of complex hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: complex-manifolds, dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I would like to know if there are in the literature explicit computations of the volume of complex hyperbolic manifolds.

More precisely, let $\mathcal O$ be an imaginary quadratic number field, and let $\Gamma$ be the set of "integer" elements in $U(n,1)$, that is
$$
\Gamma = U(n,1) \cap M(n+1,\mathcal O).
$$

How much is the volume of the complex hyperbolic manifold $M_\Gamma = H_{\mathbb C}^n / \Gamma$?

The answer for $\mathcal O=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$ is enough for me.

It's known that 
$$
\mathrm{vol}(M_\Gamma) = \frac{(-\pi)^n 2^{2n}}{(n+1)!}\; \chi(M_\Gamma),
$$
where $\chi(M_\Gamma)$ denotes the Euler characteristic of $M_\Gamma$, but I couldn't find computed the term $\chi(M_\Gamma)$ in the literature.

Thank you in advance.-.

Comment: Googling "volume + complex hyperbolic manifold" may help; it will direct you e.g. to papers by John Parker:
http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.dmj/1077230453
or to papers by Saar Hersonsky and Frederic Paulin:
http://www.math.uga.edu/~saarh/Papers/VolCom.pdf

Comment: I did it, but I couldn't find the explicit answer, including in these papers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer belongs to the second author of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5281) (=:[ES]).

First, let $\Gamma_0 = SU(n, 1) \cap M(n + 1, \mathcal O)$ and $M_0 = H_\mathbb{C}^n / \Gamma_0$. By (1) and (28) in [ES], we obtain that
$$
\mathrm{vol}(M_0) = \frac{(4 \pi)^n}{(n + 1)!} |d_{\mathcal O}|^s \left( \prod_{j = 1}^n \frac{j!}{(2 \pi)^{j + 1}} \right) \zeta(2) L_{\mathcal O}(3) \zeta(4) L_{\mathcal O}(5) \cdots F(n + 1),
$$
where $d_{\mathcal O}$ is the discriminant of $\mathcal O$, $s$ is $\frac{n (n + 3)}{4}$ when $n$ is even and $\frac{(n - 1)(n - 2)}{4}$ when $n$ is odd, and $F(n + 1)$ is $\zeta(n + 1)$ when $n$ is odd and $L_{\mathcal O}(n + 1)$ when $n$ is even.

Now, we have a finite-sheeted covering $M_0 \to M:= H_\mathbb{C}^n / \Gamma$, so 
$$
\mathrm{vol}(M)=[PU(n, 1; \mathcal O) : PSU(n, 1; \mathcal O)]\; \mathrm{vol}(M_0).
$$

An easy computation shows that the index $[PU(n, 1; \mathcal O) : PSU(n, 1; \mathcal O)]$ is equal to 
$$
1 \quad\text{if $n$ is even and $d_{\mathcal O}<-3$},
$$
$$
1 \quad\text{if $n$ is even, $d_{\mathcal O}=-3$ and $n\not\equiv 2\pmod6$},
$$
$$
3 \quad\text{if $n$ is even, $d_{\mathcal O}=-3$ and $n\equiv 2\pmod6$},
$$
$$
2 \quad\text{if $n$ is odd and $d_{\mathcal O}<-3$},
$$
$$
2 \quad\text{if $n$ is odd, $d_{\mathcal O}=-3$ and $n\equiv1\pmod6$,}
$$
$$
1 \quad\text{if $n$ is odd, $d_{\mathcal O}=-3$ and $n\equiv3\pmod6$},
$$
$$
6 \quad\text{if $n$ is odd, $d_{\mathcal O}=-3$ and $n\equiv5\pmod6$}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no general way to compute this. For complex surfaces, see

MR0653917 (84i:14025) 
Holzapfel, R.-P.
Invariants of arithmetic ball quotient surfaces. 
Math. Nachr. 103 (1981), 117–153.

and

R. Langlands
Langlands, R. P.
The volume of the fundamental domain for some arithmetical subgroups of Chevalley groups. 1966 Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Boulder, Colo., 1965) pp. 143–148 Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I.

Comment: I will consider the Langlands' paper for a general case. Thank you.-.